# Website project (ASP.NET) - what assembly will my code compile to?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, assemblies, compilation

I've got a Website project in VS.NET 2008. I have a class in App_Code folder

```
namespace RM{
    public class MyClass{
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to know **what assembly this will compile to?** You'd think it should be RM.dll but doesn't look like it.

I know that it's better to use WebApplication project instead, but it's not an option at this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't be RM.dll. If your website is not precompiled, then you won't know the name beforehand. It will be a name like this:

```
App_Web_t70fesfi.dll
```

You can determine this at runtime from with:

```
typeof(MyClass).Assembly.GetName()
```

Or, if you really need to know in advance, you can put this in an external class library that the web project references.

Comment: thanx, external class library is the way to go then !

Comment: one more question, how to avoid circular reference if i rely on assemblied from my WEBSITE project, but I'd need to reference back to this class library from that same website?